# Decorating base class method in child classes with different arguments

Tags: python

I have below piece of code and what i am trying to achieve as follows. I have a base class named `Base` and it has 2 sublcasses `A` and `B`. Both child classes have a method which does exactly same thing at its core level but then i am decorating the class methods in child classes with different arguments.

What i want to achieve is to eliminate some duplicate since it does same thing and put it in the `Base` class.

```
class Base(object):
    pass

class A(Base):
    @some_decorator(params = ('x', 'y'))
     def some_method(self):
         return "hello"

class B(Base):
    @some_decorator(params = ('a', 'b'))
     def some_method(self):
         return "hello"
```

So is it possible to move `some_method` to `Base` and then somehow we can call that in child classes and then decorate it with different arguments. I know its not really straight forward as method is not actually defined in the child classes.

**Edit**

Here is what i am trying to come up with

```
class Base(object):
    args = ()
    @some_decorator(params = args)
     def some_method(self):
         return "hello"


class A(Base):
    args = ('x', 'y')
    pass

class B(Base):
    args = ('a', 'b')
```

The issue with this is when i call the method from child class it is called with empty `args` tuple which is defined in the `Base`, so i tried modifying the actual decorator call like this

`@format_list_users(params=self.__class__.args)`

But this fails and throws error that `self` is not defined

Comment: Can you make the arguments of the decorator some kind of attribute on the child classes and then modify the decorator to not receive parameters but read attributes from the objects whose method it is decorating? It is possible, but I'm asking if you have freedom to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this like below, now it seems a very small change but then I had to scratch my head around this for a while.

```
def some_decorator(params=None, func=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(some_decorator, params)
    def wrapper(obj):
        print(getattr(obj, params))    # doing some stuff with args passed
        func(obj)    # actual method class
    return wrapper


class Base(object):
    args = ()
    @some_decorator(params = 'args')
     def some_method(self):
         return "hello"


class A(Base):
    args = ('x', 'y')
    pass

class B(Base):
    args = ('a', 'b')
```